# Wikidata query throwing StackOverflowError after update

Tags: sql, sparql, wikidata

Before, my query worked perfectly. However, something changed on their backend, and now I'm getting an error when running this [query](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fperson%20%3FpersonLabel%20%3FpersonDescription%20%28GROUP_CONCAT%28DISTINCT%20%3Fdob%20%3B%20SEPARATOR%20%3D%20%27%20%7C%20%27%29%20AS%20%3Fdob%29%20%28GROUP_CONCAT%28DISTINCT%20%3Fgender%20%3B%20SEPARATOR%20%3D%20%27%20%7C%20%27%29%20AS%20%3Fgender%29%20%28GROUP_CONCAT%28DISTINCT%20%3Fimage%20%3B%20SEPARATOR%20%3D%20%27%20%7C%20%27%29%20AS%20%3Fimage%29%20%0A%20%20WHERE%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Amwapi%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Aapi%20%22EntitySearch%22%20.%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Aendpoint%20%22www.wikidata.org%22%20.%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20mwapi%3Asearch%20%22william%22%20.%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20mwapi%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20.%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fperson%20wikibase%3AapiOutputItem%20mwapi%3Aitem%20.%20%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fperson%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ5%20.%20%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fperson%20wdt%3AP569%20%3Fdob%20%7D%20%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fperson%20wdt%3AP21%20%3Fgender%20%7D%20%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fperson%20wdt%3AP18%20%3Fimage%20%7D%20%0A%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20.%20%7D%20%0A%20%20%7D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fperson%20%3FpersonLabel%20%3FpersonDescription).

```
SELECT ?person ?personLabel ?personDescription (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?dob ; SEPARATOR = ' | ') AS ?dob) (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?gender ; SEPARATOR = ' | ') AS ?gender) (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?image ; SEPARATOR = ' | ') AS ?image) 
  WHERE { 
    SERVICE wikibase:mwapi { 
      bd:serviceParam wikibase:api "EntitySearch" . 
      bd:serviceParam wikibase:endpoint "www.wikidata.org" . 
      bd:serviceParam mwapi:search "william" . 
      bd:serviceParam mwapi:language "en" . 
      ?person wikibase:apiOutputItem mwapi:item . 
    }
    ?person wdt:P31 wd:Q5 . 
    OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P569 ?dob } 
    OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P21 ?gender } 
    OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P18 ?image } 
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" . } 
  }
GROUP BY ?person ?personLabel ?personDescription
```

Comment: That query should never have worked before ... the issue is that you reassignvariable names, which afaik, isn't allowed. The proper query starts with `SELECT ?person ?personLabel ?personDescription (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?dob ; SEPARATOR = ' | ') AS ?dobs) (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?gender ; SEPARATOR = ' | ') AS ?genders) (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?image ; SEPARATOR = ' | ') AS ?images)` - you can see, I used `?dobs` instead of `?dob` and similar for the others

Comment: I had the same, can confirm that is the issue. More generally, seems like GROUP/MIN etc. label should be different than the column name.